# Tensorflow / Keras custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to write my own loss functions in Keras, which checks if the values of my prediction are existing in the labels in any order.

Here is a code example written in python:

```py
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    n_values = 5
    loss = 0
    for i in range(n_values):
        if y_pred[i] not in y_true:
            loss += 1
    return loss
```

I have no idea how to write this code with `keras.backend`. I am not even able to find the docs for the keras functions like `backend.sum(..), .flatten` etc.

Comment: Use Tensorflow ops like `tf.reduce_sum`

Comment: Thanks. So seams like, backend was move to tf.math and your idea is great.

Comment: Backend used to be useful when Keras could be used with either Tensorflow or Caffe, but Keras isn't multi-backend anymore (Tensorflow only). So just use Tensorflow directly, and cut the middle-man